# numpy filters doesnt' work on nullable values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have these code snippets

```
deal['incash_potential'] = np.where(
    np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x != None and y != None)(deal.present_value, deal.fee),
    np.vectorize(lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y))(deal.fee, deal.present_value),
    None
)
```

deal is a pandas dataframe

in the column deal.fee I have some nullable values (python None)
but whem a run this code it's raised to me:

```
np.vectorize(lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y))(deal.fee, deal.present_value),
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in dot
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

the column deal.present_value doesn't have nullable values, they are all float

why np.where filter doesn't work?

Comment: You can't check `None` using `!=`, you need to do `x is not None`.

Comment: For more information, see https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/.

Comment: still raise the error :/

Comment: The same error?

Comment: yes, the same...

Comment: if I just do  np.where(np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x is not None and y is not None)(deal.present_value, deal.fee), True, False)

its return the correct filter
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True])
but still raise the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `np.where(cond, a, b)`, it will first evaluate `a` and `b` and then choose which value is returned depending on the condition. What this means for you is that numpy tries to compute `np.dot(x,y)` for the *entire* dataset (essentially, the sum of the element-wise product of `deal.present_value` and `deal.fee`), but it cannot because that would require multiplying a `float` with a `None`.

I think you intended to take the product (you only have two numbers, so a dot product isn't necessary) of `deal.present_value` and `deal.fee` when neither is `None`, and put `None` if either of them is `None`.

Instead of using `np.where`, you can use list comprehension and take the product when the condition is satisfied.

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
a = rng.random(10).tolist()
b = rng.random(10).tolist()

a[5] = None
b[2] = None

c = [_a*_b if _a is not None and _b is not None else None for _a, _b in zip(a, b)]
print(c)
```

Output:

```py
[0.2869813736474069, 0.4067371723227025, None, 0.5737676446323813, 0.04175957326128496, None, 0.4221164995176159, 0.05016446708421002, 0.10603083595948919, 0.284492762833831]
```